How to register and call a struct function correctly using Go HTML template
I am new to GO html templates and I am attempting to register and call a struct function GetKinInfo that is linked to the Profile struct  that returns a map and an error, however I get the following error when attempting to execute the program:
"template: index.html:85:4: executing \"index.html\" at <call GetKinInfo>: error calling call: non-function of type map[string]interface {}

How can the function be correctly registered to and called from the template ?
Below is the code I am working with:

var (
    path     string
    path_err error
)

type (
    Name struct {
        Firstname string
        Lastname  string
    }

    Contact struct {
        Email       string
        PhoneNumber string
    }

    Bank struct {
        BankName    string
        BankBranch  string
        BankAccNo   string
        BankAccName string
    }

    Kin struct {
        KinFirstName    string
        KinLastName     string
        KinPhoneNumber  int
        KinEmailAddress string
    }

    Profile struct {
        Name
        Contact
        Bank
        Kin
    }
)

func (p Profile) GetKinInfo() (map[string]any, error) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(p.Kin)
    length := t.NumField()
    if length == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no fields defined in `kin` struct")
    }
    v := reflect.ValueOf(p.Kin)
    fields := make(map[string]any, length)
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        value := v.Field(i)
        fields[field.Name] = value.Interface()
    }
    return fields, nil

}

func init() {
    path, path_err = filepath.Abs("./cmd/pkg")
    if path_err != nil {
        log.Panic("get dir failed - ", "error:", path_err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("absolute path - ", "path:", path)
}


func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("GET /", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        profile := Profile{
            Name: Name{
                Firstname: "FirstName",
                Lastname:  "LastName",
            },
            Contact: Contact{
                Email:       "youremail@gmail.com",
                PhoneNumber: "123456789",
            },
            Bank: Bank{
                BankName:    "Your Bank",
                BankBranch:  "Your Branch",
                BankAccNo:   "047310934084",
                BankAccName: "Your Name",
            },
            Kin: Kin{
                KinFirstName:    "KinFirsrName",
                KinLastName:     "KinLastName",
                KinPhoneNumber:  123456789,
                KinEmailAddress: "kin.email@gmnail.com",
            },
        }

        
        tmpl, err := template.
            New("index.html").
            Funcs(template.FuncMap{"GetKinInfo": profile.GetKinInfo}).
            ParseFiles(fmt.Sprint(path, "/index.html"))
        if err != nil {
            slog.Error("parse file failed", "error", err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        if err := tmpl.Execute(w, profile); err != nil {
            slog.Error("execute template failed", "error", err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}


Below is the html file I am using

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<title>A Title</title>
<h1>Profile</h1>
<body>
  <h4>
    <u>Personal Information</u>
  </h4>
  <p>Full Name:
    <b>{{.Firstname}} {{.Lastname}}</b>
  </p>
  <p>Email:
    <b>{{.Email}}</b>
    <br>
    <br>
  <h4> </h4><u>Banking Information</u> </h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Bank Name:
      &nbsp;
      <b>{{.BankName}}</b>
    </li>
    <li>Bank Branch:
      &nbsp;
      <b> {{.BankBranch}} </b>
    </li>
    <li>Bank Account No:
      &nbsp;
      <b>{{.BankAccNo}} </b>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h4> <u>Personal Information</u> </h4>
  {{call .GetKinInfo }} 
</body>

</html>



The whole point of registering a custom template function is so you can just do {{GetKinInfo}} (and the function name can start with a lowercase if you want). But even if you fix that, I am not sure what the output is going to be since you are dumping a map into the template. I assume you will want to be iterating over it in your template?

Yes I'll be iterating over it, this was just to prove the concept of invoking a function using templates

@Gimby  you can post your answer as the correct answer.
